# Contract: Iterate each char inside string and numerical value check

Tags: solidity, contract-development

For example I have following string, which will be given as input from a user:

```
string str = "0-00:03"
```

Inside my contract I would like to check that:

- `str[1]` should be `-`
- `str[4]` should be `:`
- and the remaining
  characters have to be numeric value.

This operation is easy to do `C` where with pointer I can iterate each character and check its char value. But I was not able to operate this inside my contract under Solidity language.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just cast the `string` to `bytes`

```
function testStr(string str) constant returns (bool) {
    bytes memory b = bytes(str);
    if (b.length != 7)
        return false;
    for (uint i; i < 7; i++) {
        if (i==1) {
            if(b[i] != 45) return false;
        }
        else if (i == ) {
            if(b[i] != 58) return false;
        }
        else if(b[i] < 48 || b[i] > 57)
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Also for example when it pass the test, I would like to convert "03" into a uint32 variable. The thing come to my mind is: 0*10 + 3*1 <= 3. So can I do something like: (b[i] - 48) * 10 and cast result into `uint32`?@Tjaden Hess

Comment: Sounds about right